# How to return a list with Flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I'm trying to build a web page with questions and answers of a survey stored in my database. I get from my database the questions and answers in two separate lists and I'd like to return them (combining them each other) but I received this error "list object is not callable". The code is:

```
@app.route('/show/<quest>')
def show(quest):

    q_id = g.db.execute("SELECT id_survey FROM surveys WHERE survey=?",[quest]).fetchone()[0]

    a = g.db.execute("SELECT q_id,a_id FROM mesh WHERE s_id=? ORDER BY q_id",[q_id]).fetchall()

    questions=list()
    answers=list()

    for i in a:
        b = g.db.execute("SELECT question FROM questions WHERE id_questions=?",[i[0]]).fetchone()[0]
        c = g.db.execute("SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE id_aswers=?",[i[1]]).fetchone()[0]

        domande.append(b)
        risposte.append(c)

    return domande + answers
```

the desirable outcome should be:

Title of survey

question 1: answers

question 2: answers

...

and so on

P.S.: For example the 2 lists questions and answers are like this:

questions=[u'favourite color?',u'favourite color?',u'favourite color?',u'do you like pasta?',u'do you like pasta?']

answers=[u'red',u'green',u'blue',u'yes',u'no']

They always have the same length. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In flask you should return something that is sent to the browser, i.e. HTML. You can write a template and render your lists in the way you want. Have you read the quickstart? You can find more information [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#rendering-templates).

Comment: yes, I tried to write a template with HTML but then I didn't know how to manage the list there. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Thank you for the link. In html I'm having a problem how to scan the list. I see the documentation that you send me and I think I solve my problem. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@app.route('/show-quest')
def showquestion():
    questions = ['favourite color?','favourite color?','favourite color?','do you like pasta?','do you like pasta?']
    answers = ["red","green",'blue','yes','no']
    return render_template('question.html', questions=questions, answers=answers)
```

question.html

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <p>{{question[0]}}</p>
    {% for answer in answers[0:3] %}
        <p>{{answer}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it's similar to what I want but your html code print out all the answer for each question and not only the specific answer for each question.

Comment: @Frank you want one question to have one answer?

Comment: no. I want one question to have multiple answers but specific to each question. for example I want: favorite color? red green blue and do you like pasta? yes no

Comment: @Frank you can use slicing and indexes as shown, since you've stated that your lists always have the same length.