# Flask - Passing a List to a new View

Tags: python, html, flask, web-applications, flask-wtforms

I am building a web app with Flask and all of the related frameworks and libraries (Jinja, WTForms etc...). This is my first time using Flask and building a proper web application. I am having trouble figuring out how to access data in different functions in the files of my application directory.

To be clear, I want to pass the user's input (from the HTML forms) into a python function that produces a list, and then pass that list back to the HTML and display it on a web page.

For Example:

```
@app.route("/tool2", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def tool2():
form = ToolForm()

def mainfunc(var1):

    #Code related to souping

    newdata = []

    for i in list(range(2)):

    maindata = [inte.text for inte in soup.find('div', {'id':'main-content'}).find_all('a', {'class': 'main-info'})]

        if var1 == 'x':
            for i2 in maindata:
                rda = i2 
                newdata.append(rda)
        elif var1 == 'y':
            for i3 in maindata:
                rda = "-" + i3 + "-"
                newdata.append(rda)
        elif var1 == 'z':
            for i4 in maindata:
                rda = '+' + i4 + '+'
                newdata.append(rda)
        else:
            redirect(url_for('tool3')) # <-- This is not working either, if someone wants to be generous and enlighten me on that as well.



        print(newdata)

        testpagecount += 1


if form.validate_on_submit():
    mainfunc(form.tester.data)


return render_template('tool2.html', title='Tool-Active', form=form)
```

I want to print `newdata` on the web page through the html, but if I try to call it, nothing happens (It doesn't print, I also do not receive any errors).

My HTML code is (no matter where I try to print `newdata` in the html, it doesn't print):

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend>Tester</legend>


            <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.var1.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.var1.errors %}
                    {{ form.var1(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for errors in form.var1.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.var1(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>


        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submittool(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="border-top pt-3">
    <small class="text-muted">
        Learn More <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a>
    </small>
</div>
<div class="media-body">

    <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ newdata }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ newdata }}</small>
    </div>
<p> {{ newdata }} </p>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

My question is, how can I pass a variable from the Python function to the HTML, and have it displayed on the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears Flask doesn't like nested functions. I got it to work by just removing the function call under the conditional, and just putting the function code under the conditional instead, like:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    newdata = []

    for i in list(range(2)):

        maindata = [inte.text for inte in soup.find('div', {'id':'main-content'}).find_all('a', {'class': 'main-info'})]

        if var1 == 'x':
            for i2 in maindata:
                rda = i2 
                newdata.append(rda)
        elif var1 == 'y':
            for i3 in maindata:
                rda = "-" + i3 + "-"
                newdata.append(rda)
        elif var1 == 'z':
            for i4 in maindata:
                rda = '+' + i4 + '+'
                newdata.append(rda)
        else:
            redirect(url_for('tool3')) # <-- This is not working either, if someone wants to be generous and enlighten me on that as well.



    print(newdata)

    testpagecount += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have populated successfully your `newlist`, then inside `mainfunc`, you can return the following:

`return render_template('tool2.html', title='Tool-Active', form=form, mynewlist=newlist)`

Then, inside your `tool2.html` view you can iterate through this returned list as follows:

```
<ul>{% for item in mynewlist %}
  <li>item</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: By mynewlist do you mean the variable 'newdata' I had? I tried that and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Remember, you are returning the variable and rendering the `tool2.html`, thus it should be available inside that `.html` file, so you should iterate/loop over your list inside the returned html file; here is a similar question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592484/how-to-return-a-list-with-flask

Comment: I'm not getting an error, and it does seem to autofill the list as a parameter when I start typing it (so it's finding it), it just doesn't seem to display on the page. Do I need to get rid of my other "render_template"?

Comment: I appreciate your help, the HTML now autocompletes the variables that I pass in to my return_template parameters (so I will upvote you for that). So I am assuming it is successfully passing them through, I also know that the list is successfully being populated through print()...strangely they still will not display on the webpage despite being present in the HTML and fully populated as per the print results in my command prompt.

Comment: Did you consider not combining POST and GET in the same function? Make two views, one will get the input from the user and put in a list, the other view will take the list and display it in another html, when the user click on a button, for example. Refactoring your views in a simpler version might help you debug it easier. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I did try passing it to another html file and I got the same issue. It returns nothing (not 'none' or an error, just nothing at all as if it's returning it but it's not populated.). Could it be a problem that mainfunc() is nested within the original tool2() function?

Comment: not sure your indentation is correct in general, since your `tool2()` doesn't seem to have something inside, if this is the original indentation and not modified by the formatting of the post...reproduce the exact layout of the code in your view as in the file, it's hard to understand what goes where from the post

Comment: Also, the good old `print` can help you inside those functions, and you can see what the actual data in the list is; you'll visualize your printed lines in the same terminal where you run your app, just another way of debugging...

Comment: I appreciate the help but I'm stumped at this point. I've even tried rendering a different window. The terminal IS showing the printed list, so the list is definitely being populated. The text classes that the list should be printed in, are showing up but just not returning anything, as if the list is empty, yet the terminal prints it totally populated. I tried rendering it all in a "tool3" window, but I get the exact same issue (and for some reason url_for won't work so I have to type it manually). Like I said before too, it's autocompleting so the HTML is finding it, just with nothing.

Comment: It almost seems like it's not running that final return statement